I have to call delete API from another service, which rest template method i can use
I have to call a delete API from another service which required a CartRequestDTO to perform the operation. Which REST template method can I use to send the CartRequestDTO to call the service.
private String carturl="http://localhost:8091/cart";

public ResponseEntity deleteproductincart(@RequestBody CartRequestDTO cartRequestDTO){
    String deleteurl=carturl+"/deleteproductincart";

    RestTemplate restTemplate= restTemplateBuilder.build();


    restTemplate.exchange(deleteurl,HttpMethod.DELETE,null,cartRequestDTO);

    return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.OK);
}

I am trying to call this API  http://localhost:8091/cart/deleteproductincart which is running separately from the above service
@DeleteMapping("/deleteproductincart")
public ResponseEntity deleteproductincart(@RequestBody CartRequestDTO cartRequestDTO){
    String validateuserurl="http://localhost:8090/users/validateuserandtoken/" + cartRequestDTO.getUser_Id()
            +"/"+cartRequestDTO.getToken();

    return cartService.deleteproductincart(cartRequestDTO);
}

Service class:
@Transactional
public ResponseEntity deleteproductincart(CartRequestDTO cartRequestDTO) {
   Cart cart= cartRepository.findbyuserIdandproductname(cartRequestDTO.getUser_Id(),cartRequestDTO.getProductname());
   Product product= productRepository.findbyname(cartRequestDTO.getProductname());
   long ans=cart.getQuantity()-cartRequestDTO.getQuantity();
   if(ans==0){
       productRepository.deletbycartid(cart.getId());
       cartRepository.delete(cart);

       return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.OK);
   }
   cart.setQuantity(ans);
   cart.setTotalcost(cart.getTotalcost()- cartRequestDTO.getQuantity()*product.getPrice());
   cart.setAddedat(new Date());
   cartRepository.save(cart);
   return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.OK);
}

@Getter
@Setter
public class CartRequestDTO {

    private long User_Id;
    private String Productname;
    private long quantity;
    private String token;
}

I tried using exchange but stuck here not sure how to proceed.

What is the error you are getting ?
